# Get last part of string after hyphen

Tags: command-line, sed, awk, command, string

Is there a simple command line to extract the last part of a string separated by hyphens? E.g., I want to extract `123` from `foo-bar-123`.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can use Bash's [parameter expansion](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/073?action=show&redirect=ParameterExpansion):

```
string="foo-bar-123" && printf "%s\n" "${string##*-}"
123
```

If you want to use another process, with Awk:

```
echo "foo-bar-123" | awk -F- '{print $NF}'
```

Or, if you prefer Sed:

```
echo "foo-bar-123" | sed 's/.*-//'
```

A lighter external process, as [Glenn Jackman suggests](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/193482/get-last-part-of-string-after-hyphen#comment324049_193483) is `cut`:

```
cut -d- -f3 <<< "$string"
```

Comment: shell parameter expansion is the best answer. A lightweight external tool is `cut`: `cut -d- -f3 <<< "$string"`

Comment: @glennjackman - re: `cut`; indeed but only if the number of the last field is known (as the question is a bit ambiguous: _Is there a simple command line to extract the last part... ?_ )

Comment: @don_crissti, indeed. One *could* do `rev <<< "$string" | cut -d- -f1 | rev`, but then we're veering away from the simplicity of param.expansion.

Answer (score 4):

```
echo "foo-bar-123"| awk -F"-" '{print $3}'
```

Comment: If you know in advance how many hyphens an input string will have you can edit `$3` to some other number, otherwise this techinique won't work.

Answer (score 3):

```
grep -Po '(?<=\w-)\w+(?=$|[\s.,])'
```